# How were the electrons, protons counted in an atom?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, protons, elements

The title says it all! In high school I remember it being taught as a religion, I had to believe the count (hydrogen has 1 proton, carbon has 6 etc...) , but how can I be sure I was told the truth?

Comment: I think Aminos deserves more credit for his question than he was given. Niels' answer missed the mark. It is very like religion to rely on the authority of the teacher. Asking how do I know the teacher's statements are true is a scientific attitude, not a religious one. It is very like religion to rely on the authority of 100 years of experiments if you don't know what they are. Yes, experiments are the basis of how we know. Yes, experiment vs faith is the basic difference between science and religion. But he wasn't asking about that difference. He was asking "What is the science?"

Comment: Here is a historical context of how the periodic structure of elements was found. The concept of "atoms" existed  since ancient times and was developed after the exit from the middle ages https://www.asbmb.org/asbmb-today/science/020721/a-brief-history-of-the-periodic-table

Comment: "but how can I be sure I was told the truth?" Go and count them. Go look and see. Now the hard part will be for you to figure out how to look and see.

Comment: Hence my question (2 downvotes wow) ! Can you give me some information about the experiences ? I have been looking for years for information on these famous experiences and I can't find anything on the Internet. Since the pandemic, I'm trying to set the record straight on several topics (maths, computer science, physics, "big pharma" LOL...)

Comment: why do we mean by number of protons ? is it really the number of protons or somekind of ratio ? and if it's a ratio why not use a more precise name unambiguously.

Comment: what has been affirmed without proof can also be denied without proof

Comment: By number of protons and electrons, we mean the same thing as number of rocks. The number of electrons in an atom is the basis of all chemistry. Physics and chemistry are straight descriptions of how the universe works. It sounds like you need to understand them more than set the record straight. If you have doubts about the truth of them, there are plenty of experiments you can do at home. Try https://brilliant.org/ or Google Home chemistry experiments for adults.

Comment: @mmesser314 I accept the concept of electrons and protons and the electric neutrality, I just want some infos on how they can be counted, look at my comment on the secondary answer to this question, I talked about electric charge, maybe it has been used to count the electrons (and hence the protons) idk.

Comment: I think this question does a great job of exposing how many us are experts simply in perpetuating scientific dogma (correct though it may be), and how few of us can recount the historical experimental details that led us to the truths we have today.

Answer (score 1):

What you were taught was the result of about 100 years of experiments, which furnished us with the periodic table of the elements. You can rely on those experiments! Oh and BTW it is not *religion* to acknowledge the factual accuracy of the periodic table, because it is based on experiment.

Comment: Can you give me some information about the experiences.

Comment: I guess it's based on weighing different things and comparing the mass of them, but I want accurate information on this topic because it's still not real to me, I can't believe it (just like the islamic religious BS I was fed with when I was a kid).

Comment: what has been affirmed without proof can also be denied without proof

Comment: was the electric charge (Milikan's experiment) used to determine the number of electrons ?

Comment: Yes, according to this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35504/how-do-scientists-count-the-exact-number-of-electrons-protons-neutrons-in-the I am software developer but I got more curiosity than you guys working in Physics

Comment: @Aminos you are misreading the horror of the "you guys"... not lack of curiosity. The answer is a standard part of their specialized curriculum, and they know that any succinct answer would be "lies to children". It is a delightful long story, and you might have gotten suggestions for sources, if only you asked properly... As it stands, your question  reads like crackpot contrariness....

Answer (score 1):

I think you accept, that an atom consists of a nucleus and surrounding electrons? And that the whole thing is neutral?
Ok, then you can strip off the electrons step by step by irradiating appropriate electromagnetic waves. You then have the number of electrons.
Since the atom is neutral, the nucleus itself must have the same number of charges.
Then you can measure the mass of the nucleus using mass spectroscopy.
Do this for several elements and you can see that they differ roughly by the same amount from one to the next.
You will also find that there are isotopes of the same element.

Putting this together gets you our established atom model:

Mass = n * neutrons + m * Protons

Comment: "You then have the number of electrons." How ? I know that from Milikan's experiment that we have already determined the "elementary charge", is the latter can be used to count the number of electrons ? Can we strip an atom from all its electrons ? and maybe then weigh the mass of a chemical element that doesn't have electrons ?

Comment: Yes, I accept that an atom consists of a nucleus and the electrons that surround it. I have found some interesting videos on this subject on YouTube and I quite agree with the experiments and conclusions.

Comment: "Can we strip an atom from all its electrons?" - Yes you can, even step by step.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35504/how-do-scientists-count-the-exact-number-of-electrons-protons-neutrons-in-the?newreg=1955696909a24b5d8380313b37f1ff35